# julia create an empty dataframe and append rows to it

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying out the Julia DataFrames module. I am interested in it so I can use it to plot simple simulations in Gadfly. I want to be able to iteratively add rows to the dataframe and I want to initialize it as empty.

The tutorials/documentation on how to do this is sparse (most documentation describes how to analyse imported data).

To append to a nonempty dataframe is straightforward:

```
df = DataFrame(A = [1, 2], B = [4, 5])
push!(df, [3 6])
```

This returns.

```
3x2 DataFrame
| Row | A | B |
|-----|---|---|
| 1   | 1 | 4 |
| 2   | 2 | 5 |
| 3   | 3 | 6 |
```

But for an empty init I get errors.

```
df = DataFrame(A = [], B = [])
push!(df, [3, 6])
```

Error message:

```
ArgumentError("Error adding 3 to column :A. Possible type mis-match.")
while loading In[220], in expression starting on line 2
```

What is the best way to initialize an empty Julia DataFrame such that you can iteratively add items to it later in a for loop?

Comment: I could not reproduce this error message in DataFrames v. 0.7.4 on Julia 0.4.5.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A zero length array defined using only **[]** will lack sufficient type information.

```
julia> typeof([])
Array{None,1}
```

So to avoid that problem is to simply indicate the type.

```
julia> typeof(Int64[])
Array{Int64,1}
```

And you can apply that to your DataFrame problem

```
julia> df = DataFrame(A = Int64[], B = Int64[])
0x2 DataFrame

julia> push!(df, [3  6])

julia> df
1x2 DataFrame
| Row | A | B |
|-----|---|---|
| 1   | 3 | 6 |
```

Comment: What about the situation where you know how big the DataFrame will wind up? Is it more efficient to initialize it up front? For example `DataFrame(Int64, 1000, 10)` Then what's the syntax for populating each row as you iterate?

Comment: @bjmc I was wondering the same thing. Eventually found out and added an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

The answer from @waTeim already answers the initial question. But what if I want to **dynamically** create an empty `DataFrame` and append rows to it. E.g. what if I don't want hard-coded column names?

In this case, `df = DataFrame(A = Int64[], B = Int64[])` is not sufficient.
The `NamedTuple` `A = Int64[], B = Int64[]` needs to be create dynamically.

Let's assume we have a vector of column names `col_names` and a vector of column types `colum_types` from which to create an empty`DataFrame`.

```
col_names = [:A, :B] # needs to be a vector Symbols
col_types = [Int64, Float64]
# Create a NamedTuple (A=Int64[], ....) by doing
named_tuple = (; zip(col_names, type[] for type in col_types )...)

df = DataFrame(named_tuple) # 0×2 DataFrame
```

Alternatively, the `NameTuple` could be created with

```
# or by doing
named_tuple = NamedTuple{Tuple(col_names)}(type[] for type in col_types )
```

Answer (score 4):

```
using Pkg, CSV, DataFrames

iris = CSV.read(joinpath(Pkg.dir("DataFrames"), "test/data/iris.csv"))

new_iris = similar(iris, nrow(iris))

head(new_iris, 2)
# 2×5 DataFrame
# │ Row │ SepalLength │ SepalWidth │ PetalLength │ PetalWidth │ Species │
# ├─────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────┤
# │ 1   │ missing     │ missing    │ missing     │ missing    │ missing │
# │ 2   │ missing     │ missing    │ missing     │ missing    │ missing │

for (i, row) in enumerate(eachrow(iris))
    new_iris[i, :] = row[:]
end

head(new_iris, 2)

# 2×5 DataFrame
# │ Row │ SepalLength │ SepalWidth │ PetalLength │ PetalWidth │ Species │
# ├─────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────┤
# │ 1   │ 5.1         │ 3.5        │ 1.4         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
# │ 2   │ 4.9         │ 3.0        │ 1.4         │ 0.2        │ setosa  │
```

Answer (score 1):

I think at least in the latest version of Julia you can achieve this by creating a pair object without specifying type

```
df = DataFrame("A" => [], "B" => [])
push!(df, [5,'f'])

1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ A    B   
     │ Any  Any 
─────┼──────────
   1 │ 5    f
```

as seen in this [post](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-make-empty-dataframe-with-column-names/77936) by @Bogumił Kamiński where multiple columns are needed, something like this can be done:

```
entries = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
df = DataFrame([ name =>[] for name in entries])
```

```
julia> push!(df,[4,5,'r','p'])
1×4 DataFrame
 Row │ A    B    C    D   
     │ Any  Any  Any  Any 
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 4    5    r    p
```

Or as pointed out by @Antonello below if you know that type you can do.

```
df = DataFrame([name => Int[] for name in entries])
```

which is also in @Bogumil Kaminski's original post.

Comment: Still having the inner columns being of `Any` type would not be the best for performances. If you know the type the columns will host, use this info.

Comment: Got it! thanks for pointing that out!