# Preallocate a data frame of known size in Julia

Tags: julia

When I'm running simulations, I like to initialize a big, empty array and fill it up as the simulation iterates through to the end. I do this with something like `res = Array(Real,(n_iterations,n_parameters))`. However, it would be nice to have named columns, which I think means using a DataFrame. Yet when I try to do something like `res_df = convert(DataFrame,res)` it throws an error. I would like a more concise approach than doing something like `res_df = DataFrame(a=Array(Real,N),b=Array(Real,N),c=Array(Real,N),....)` as suggested by the answers to: [julia create an empty dataframe and append rows to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201005/julia-create-an-empty-dataframe-and-append-rows-to-it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To preallocate a data frame, you must pre-allocate its columns.  You can create three columns full of `missing` values by simply doing `[fill(missing, 10000) for _ in 1:3]`, but that doesn't actually allocate anything at all because those vectors can *only* hold one value — `missing` — and thus they can't be changed to hold other values later.  One way to do this is by using to `Vector` constructors that can hold *either* `Missing` or `Float64`:

```
julia> DataFrame([Vector{Union{Missing, Float64}}(missing, 10000) for _ in 1:3], [:a, :b, :c])
10000×3 DataFrame
   Row │ a         b         c
       │ Float64?  Float64?  Float64?
───────┼──────────────────────────────
     1 │  missing   missing   missing
     2 │  missing   missing   missing
   ⋮   │    ⋮         ⋮         ⋮
 10000 │  missing   missing   missing
                     9997 rows omitted
```

Note that rather than `Real`, this is using the concrete `Float64` — this will have significantly better performance.

(this answer was edited to reflect DataFrames v1.0 syntax)

Comment: If you know that all your columns are of the same type and that there will never be unpopulated (`NA`) elements, there may be other data structures that you can use.  Take a look at [NamedArrays.jl](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl), or if you're willing to fly by the seat of your pants and working on the unstable 0.4, you can try my recent work-in-progress [AxisArrays.jl](https://github.com/mbauman/AxisArrays.jl). Both projects aim to more directly augment the built-in `Array` with dimension names and axis metadata, whereas DataFrames uses a collection-of-columns approach.

Comment: This method is now deprecated.