# How to define an empty DataFrame with dynamically typed Column Names and Column Types in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia, dynamically-generated, dataframes.jl

Given column names and column types like these:

```
col_names = ["A", "B", "C"]
col_types = ["String", "Int64", "Bool"]
```

I want to create an empty `DataFrame` like this:

```
desired_DF = DataFrame(A = String[], B = Int64[], C = Bool[]) #But I cannot specify every column name and type like this every time.
```

How do I do this?

I seek either your code snippet for doing the needful or, if you like the following solution I've copied below, please explain it to me.

I've seen [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68557940/8055886). It works, but I do not understand it, especially the third line, in particular the semicolon at the beginning and the three dots at the end.

```
col_names = [:A, :B] # needs to be a vector Symbols
col_types = [Int64, Float64]
# Create a NamedTuple (A=Int64[], ....) by doing
named_tuple = (; zip(col_names, type[] for type in col_types )...)

df = DataFrame(named_tuple) # 0×2 DataFrame
```

Also, I was hoping that perhaps there is an even more elegant way to do the needful?

Comment: Maybe change the *Does not work* to `desired_DF = DataFrame(A = String[], B = Int64[], C = Bool[])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us start with the input:

```
julia> col_names = ["A", "B", "C"]
3-element Vector{String}:
 "A"
 "B"
 "C"

julia> col_types = [String, Int64, Bool]
3-element Vector{DataType}:
 String
 Int64
 Bool
```

Note the difference, `col_types` need to be types not strings. `col_names` are good the way you proposed.

Now there are many ways to solve your problem. Let me show you the simplest one in my opinion:

First, create a vector of vectors that will be columns of your data frame:

```
julia> [T[] for T in col_types]
3-element Vector{Vector}:
 String[]
 Int64[]
 Bool[]
```

Now you just need to pass it to `DataFrame` constructor, where this vector of vectors is a first argument, and the second argument are column names:

```
julia> DataFrame([T[] for T in col_types], col_names)
0×3 DataFrame
 Row │ A       B      C
     │ String  Int64  Bool
─────┴─────────────────────
```

and you are done.

If you would not have column names you can generate them automatically passing `:auto` as a second argument:

```
julia> DataFrame([T[] for T in col_types], :auto)
0×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1      x2     x3
     │ String  Int64  Bool
─────┴─────────────────────
```

This is a simple way to get what you want.

---

Now let us decompose the approach you mentioned above:

```
(; zip(col_names, type[] for type in col_types )...)
```

To understand it you need to know how keyword arguments can be passed to functions. See this:

```
julia> f(; kwargs...) = kwargs
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(; [(:a, 10), (:b, 20), (:c, 30)]...)
pairs(::NamedTuple) with 3 entries:
  :a => 10
  :b => 20
  :c => 30
```

Now the trick is that in the example above:

```
(; zip(col_names, type[] for type in col_types )...)
```

you use exactly this trick. Since you do not pass a name of the function a `NamedTuple` is created (this is how Julia syntax works). The `zip` part just creates you the tuples of values, like in my example function above:

```
julia> collect(zip(col_names, type[] for type in col_types ))
3-element Vector{Tuple{Symbol, Vector}}:
 (:A, String[])
 (:B, Int64[])
 (:C, Bool[])
```

So the example is the same as passing:

```
julia> (; [(:A, String[]), (:B, Int64[]), (:C, Bool[])]...)
(A = String[], B = Int64[], C = Bool[])
```

Which is, given what we have said, the same as passing:

```
julia> (; :A => String[], :B => Int64[], :C => Bool[])
(A = String[], B = Int64[], C = Bool[])
```

Which is, in turn, the same as just writing:

```
julia> (; A = String[], B = Int64[], C = Bool[])
(A = String[], B = Int64[], C = Bool[])
```

So - this is the explanation how and why the example you quoted works. However, I believe that what I propose is simpler.

Comment: Would `col_names = ["A", "B", "C"]; col_types = [String[], Int64[], Bool[]]; DataFrame(col_types, col_names)` be an alternative option?

Comment: yes, but then it is not `col_types` but just `cols` (since it is actual columns and not their types only).